# Execute an "if" condition "x" milliseconds and stop for "y"millisecond and repeat the condition ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a program that test a condition inside a if loop continuously during the run of the programme. But i want this **if condition** to become true or active for certain period of time(say for 5ms)  and then deactivate the **if condition** for next 10ms. Then continue this pattern continuously until user close the program. I have no idea to approach this, please help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a Suggestion for you...

Make a method and call this method when you want to start the process with TRUE value.

```
-(void)yourProcessMethod(BOOL _flag){

  if(_flag){
      //Execute your process 
      //now check for time is it 5ms or not
      if(time elapsed < 5ms){
          [self yourProcessMethod(TRUE)];
      }else{
          [self yourProcessMethod(FALSE)];
      }
  }else{
      //Execute your process (or do nothing if you want to stop it for 10 ms)
      //now check for time is it 10ms or not
      if(time elapsed < 10ms){
          [self yourProcessMethod(FALSE)];
      }else{
          [self yourProcessMethod(TRUE)];
      }

  }
}
```

EDITED :-

You can use this Piece of code for Checking time elapsed for executing.

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
// do stuff...
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

`timeInterval` is the difference between start and now, in seconds, with sub-millisecond precision.

Calculate the time Elapsed i.e timeInterval and check its value and compare it that whether it is < 5ms or 10 [self yourProcessMethod(TRUE/FALSE)];.

**I hope this Helps you. :)** If yes, you can accept the answer or UpVote it :)

Comment: Dear sir, I m trying to check the condition and update a counter, But my counter keeps updating, But i want to get it update during the specific period. So how can i connect this scenario -(void)yourProcessMethod(BOOL _flag) with this function?

Comment: Modified the Answer at the End , Check if its what u need.

Comment: This code will cause a stack overflow after some time. And it will consume all the CPU time and block the UI.

Comment: @phix23 :- Yes man, you are absolutely true. But i have just given him the Logic for use, putting an terminating Condition wont be much difficult, i Guess.

Comment: :O.... Thank you for your valuable answer! But i m lost, Since my application deeply consider CPU time and needs lowest computational cost. So @phix23 and mAc is there any method to get this done with the lowest CPU time consumption?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
BOOL result = NO;
BOOL prevResult = NO;

while(condition1)
{
    if(condition2)
        result = YES;
    else
        result = NO;

    if(result)
    {
        if(!prevResult)
            // Store the time
        else if(/* current time - stored time < 5ms */)
            // Make the thread sleep for 10ms
    }

    prevResult = result;
}
```

Note that it's probably not very realistic to expect millisecond-precision.

Comment: Can you please mention the condition1? I think, condition 2 you are referring is the condition that i need to check in my code. Can you mention how to make the thread sleep for 10ms? thank you!

Comment: condition1 determines when the loop should stop, you can set this to YES if the loop should run forever.
As far as I know there is no way to reliably sleep a thread for 10ms, but you could try [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.01];