# Execute an “if” condition for certain period of time and then stop it for a another period and repeat?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute an “if” condition “x” milliseconds and stop for “y”millisecond and repeat the condition ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845025/execute-an-if-condition-x-milliseconds-and-stop-for-ymillisecond-and-repea)

I have a program that test a condition inside a if loop continuously during the run of the programme. But i want this if condition to become true or active for certain period of time(say for 5ms) and then deactivate the if condition for next 10ms. Then continue this pattern continuously until user close the program!

Comment: use this: [self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]

Comment: @safecase Can you explain it bit more? thank you for ur idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it sounds like you should really take a different approach, this is the answer to your question literally:

```
while ( YES )
{
    NSTimeInterval t = [NSDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    long ms = t*1000;
    if ( ms % 15 < 5 )
    {
       // code here is executed for 5 ms in every 15 ms timewindow
    }
}
```

This loop will be *very* detrimental to app performance and battery life.

Depending on what kind of code has to be executed "for 5 ms, every 15 ms", you could use an `NSTimer` instead:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self
         selector:@selector(fire) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

with a method:

```
-(void)fire
{
    // called every 15 ms, does something for 5 ms.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer! In my program i fill my array(size6) with 6 accelerometer data and use them to calculate a output value using an equation. Then i insert this output value to a another array(size 6). I delete last element of both arrays every time i add a new element. With this u can understand the importance of CPU time and then i want to compare two of those calculated output values inside a if condition and update a counter. So this is where i wanted to apply this timing condition so that it checks the condition for a certain period defined and update counter if satisfied

Comment: Is this method proposed by you is computational cost wise better? And you relate it bit to my scenario. I m bit new to programming n these questions keep me wondering! Appreciate ur valuable answers!

Comment: hello i m expecting a reply from you! :)

Comment: @sam if possible, you should take action on accelerometer data as it comes in. You receive the measurements in some function, which is the place to do this. This will save battery life and give a better response, since you will take action right after the accelerometer reading comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition with `||` and a bool flag indication should it be checked or not. `if(shouldNotCheckCondition || condition)`

Comment: Thank you for ue answer! Can you please explain it bit more! :)

Comment: If you set your `shouldNotCheckCondition` to `true` then your condition will not matter.